# Convert Dictionary to String in MVC Razor View for HTML.ActionLink

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, razor, html.actionlink

I have a `Dictionary<string, string>` with key values that are used for the `HTML.ActionLink` links. Mostly the `TKeys` are used but if there is a `TValue` that's not empty I would like to use that instead. The reason is that for UI reasons some words work better than the controller action name, like *GetUserProfile* is better displayed as *User Profile*.

`Html.ActionLink` is throwing this error:

> CS1928: 'System.Web.Mvc.HtmlHelper' does not contain a definition for 'ActionLink' and the best extension method overload
> 'System.Web.Mvc.Html.LinkExtensions.ActionLink(System.Web.Mvc.HtmlHelper,
> string, string, string, object, object)' has some invalid arguments

I'm pretty sure that it's because it's seeing the `Dictionary<string, string>` type and not the `string` type. So is there a way to convert the Dictionary `TKey/TValue` into a `string` type to satisfy what it's asking for? Or another way I'm not thinking to accomplish the same task?

```
@{
  Dictionary<string, string> nav = new Dictionary<string, string>()    {{ "Email", "" }, { "Username", "" }, { "EditProfile", "Edit Profile" }}; 
}

@foreach (var navItem in nav)
{
  if (navItem.Value.IsEmpty())
  {        
        
    <li>
        @Html.ActionLink(navItem.Key, navItem, "ControllerName")
    </li>
   }
  else
   {
    <li>
        @Html.ActionLink(navItem.Value, navItem, "ControllerName")
    </li>
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using [`ActionLink(HtmlHelper, String, String, String)`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.web.mvc.html.linkextensions.actionlink?view=aspnet-mvc-5.2#system-web-mvc-html-linkextensions-actionlink(system-web-mvc-htmlhelper-system-string-system-string-system-string)) with the second argument (count after the `HtmlHelper` as it is an extension method) that expects a `string` value.

While you are providing the value of `KeyValuePair<string, string>` to the second argument. I believe what you want is to provide the `navItem.Key` as `actionName`.

```
@foreach (var navItem in nav)
{
  if (navItem.Value.IsEmpty())
  {        
        
    <li>
        @Html.ActionLink(navItem.Key, navItem.Key, "ControllerName")
    </li>
   }
  else
   {
    <li>
        @Html.ActionLink(navItem.Value, navItem.Key, "ControllerName")
    </li>
  }
}
```

Comment: how did I miss that. I updated my code to look like your answer and it worked.

Comment: You are welcome. And I think it can be simplified to `@Html.ActionLink(navItem.Value.IsEmpty() ? navItem.Key : navItem.Value, navItem.Key, "ControllerName")` by using the ternary conditional operator. So you no need the if-else statement with different templates.